# Is there a JQuery Plugin that overlays tips on top of the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

If you take a look at that, you'll see that there's an overlay, with arrows pointing to how to use the webpage.

Is there a JQuery plugin that does this? (automatically ties the arrow to the dom elements)?

Comment: I like pictures to be in questions. That would be more helpful. If you do I remove downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been using that a lot and I think that it just does the trick!

Comment: Plugin is no longer supported it read on site.  They redirect here now: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but I doubt there is a plugin that would display an overlay with images directly connected to certain elements of the DOM as it is such a bespoke thing to do.

However, it would not be too tricky to achieve through the use of the CSS `display` and `position: absolute` properties.